# Prohibit edge node intersections

Tags: graph, position, graphviz, dot, image-graphviz

my question is how to prevent my edge crossing its node, when rendering a DoT file using Graphviz. I have seen various questions on StackOverflow regarding my question, which eventually boiled down to setting `overlap=false` or setting the anchor (see `:n`, `:s` in minimal example below) in combination with `rank` and `splines` properly. However, I still get an edge crossing my node. Setting the anchors even makes it worse. I don't get what I am doing wrong. I have read and tried several things from the docs like `scalexy`, `overlap_scaling`, etc. and none of them worked or even had an effect. Could someone explain me what I am doing wrong. Is there probably a setting I made, which is not compatible with the `overlap=false` setting?

You find a minimal example below:

```
digraph minimal_example {
  overlap=false;
  overlap_scaling=5;
  rankdir=RL;
  splines=line;

 "a" 
 "g" [shape=diamond, color=red] 

 "a" -> "f"; {rank=same; "f"; "a"}
 "g":n -> "b":s; {rank=same; "b"; "g"}
 "f" -> { "d" "b" }
 "b" -> { "c" }
 "c" -> { "d" }
 "d" -> { "e" }
 "e" -> {  }
}
```

[image]

**Rendering via:** `dot -Tsvg -Nshape=rect -o output.svg

**Desired outcome:** Move node `g` below node `b`. The idea was to achieve this main goal by prohibiting these ugly intersection between nodes and edges.

**Version:** `dot - graphviz version 2.43.0 (0)`

**System**: `Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS`

Answer (score 1):

- `rankdir=RL;` makes an interesting graph
- **overlap** (and **overlap_scaling**) do not apply to **dot**, only to the other engines (https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/overlap/)
- `"e" -> {  }` does nothing
- `"d" -> { "e" }` (and similar) can be rewritten as `d -> e` (braces do nothing here)
- as you noted, ports do not solve this problem
- FYI, your Ubuntu version is pretty old.  But that is not causing your problems.
- relationships (`->`) in the same rank are normally shown downward, thus `g->b` is shown downward (and not where you want it)
- you might also try the other engines (**neato**, **fdp**, **circo**, **twopi** - all mad interesting output)

OK, two solutions:

```
digraph minimal_example {
  rankdir=RL;
  //splines=line;  // defaults to splines=true
  node [shape=rect]
// "a"  // oddly, removing this declaration mad a difference
 "g" [shape=diamond, color=red] 

 "a" -> "f"; {rank=same; "f"; "a"}
 "g" -> "b"; {rank=same; "b"; "g"}
 "f" -> { "d" "b" }
 "b" -> { "c" }
 "c" -> { "d" }
 "d" -> { "e" }
}
```

Giving:
[image]
Or

```
digraph minimal_example {
  rankdir=RL;
  splines=line;
  node [shape=rect]

 "g" [shape=diamond, color=red] 

 "a" -> "f"; {rank=same; "f"; "a"}
 "g" -> "b"  {rank=same; "b"; "g"}
 "f" -> { "d" "b" }
 "b" -> { "c" }
 "c" -> { "d" }
 "d" -> { "e" }
}
```

Giving:
[image]

Comment: The redundant node `"a"` that seems to make a difference as you said, was there on purpose (I define some properties there in the real scenario). But what you said is an interesting point: I noticed that changing the order of lines ` "a"` and `"g" [shape=diamond, color=red]` makes the difference. and yields the same result as in your second solution. Do you have any idea why interchanging these lines makes a difference? As a background, I auto-generate the graphs, which leads to the redundant braces you were mentioning.

Comment: Dot is quite complex (https://graphviz.org/documentation/TSE93.pdf).  To avoid tweaking your graphs, try `splines=true` or try some of the other engines.